# Using For loop in Pandas with groupby function

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

`unGrouped` is a dataframe that looks like this:

```
         date        borough
969609  01/01/2014       BROOKLYN
967983  01/01/2014          BRONX
967982  01/01/2014         QUEENS
865943  01/01/2014       BROOKLYN
967981  01/01/2014      MANHATTAN
967980  01/01/2014       BROOKLYN
967979  01/01/2014         QUEENS
967984  01/01/2014          BRONX
967978  01/01/2014         QUEENS
967976  01/01/2014       BROOKLYN
967975  01/01/2014       BROOKLYN
```

I have the following code:

```
for row in unGrouped:
if unGrouped['borough'][row]=='BRONX':
    bronxCount+=1
    print bronxCount
```

And it gives me a Key Error: `date`. 
I would like to iterate through the column `borough`, increment `bronxCount` whenever it comes across `BRONX`, and store that value for each row in a column called `bronxCount', to eventually get a count of crimes in the bronx for each day. If anyone could get this loop to work I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for these awesome suggestions! These methods all give a count for bronx crimes, but I'm looking to preserve the 'date' entry which links to the incident, so I can plot a timecourse for crimes over the course of the year. These flatten the time dimension and just give a total count, whereas I'm looking to get a count for each day (hence the initial looping). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sum up after filtering:

```
>>> (unGrouped.borough == 'BRONX').sum()
2
```

To get the counts per date just group by date  and boroug before counting:

```
>>> unGrouped.groupby(['date', 'borough']).size()
date        borough  
01/01/2014  BRONX        2
            BROOKLYN     5
            MANHATTAN    1
            QUEENS       3
dtype: int64
```

or if you only want `BRONX`with a date index.

```
>>> unGrouped.groupby(['borough', 'date']).size().loc['BRONX']
date
01/01/2014    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is it! The .loc was the missing key. Thank you so much Mike

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you're using a for loop you're probably doing it wrong!

What you probably want is a groupby and count?

```
unGrouped.groupBy('borough').size()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `values_counts`:

```
bronxCount = unGrouped.borough.value_counts()['BRONX']
print(BronxCount)
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy`

```
v, n = np.unique(df.borough.values, return_counts=True)
d=dict(zip(v, n))
d['BRONX']
Out[218]: 2
```